# Use of undeclared identifier in c

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

I am getting an undeclared identifier error in the line: "printf("%f", new_u[i]);"
Which is strange because I can print i in that for loop at it has values. Why am I getting that error?

```
const int MAX = 101;

int main(void) {

    int t = 1; //time
    int m = 0; //number of segments of bar
    int n = 0; //number of time intervals

    double new_u[MAX]; //to store temps currently being converted (array of 101 doubles)
    double old_u[MAX]; //to store temps corresponding to prev time (array of 101 doubles)

    printf("Enter number of segments: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter number of time intervals: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double h = (1.0/m); //length of bar segments
    double d = (1.0/n); //length of time interval

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) { //j is which time interval the iteration is on
        int t_j = j * d; //t_j is the actual fraction of a second the iteration is on (i.e. 0.0, 0.2, 0.4...)
        new_u[0] = new_u[m] = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
            new_u[i] = old_u[i] + d/(h*h)*(old_u[i-1] - 2*old_u[i] + old_u[i+1]);
        printf("%f", new_u[i]);
        //I need to finish code by printing new_u values
        //Then copy new_u into old_u for next pass;
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace `printf("%f", new_u[i]);` with `printf("%f", new_u[m]);`

Comment: Scope of `i` is only with in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

**As you are not using any braces for the inner for loop,so the value of `i` is not known to that `printf` statement**.In conditional and looping statements,if there are no braces  (or block created )for them,then they can only manipulate and have scope restricted only upto the statement just after there declaration.

```
for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        new_u[i] = old_u[i] + d/(h*h)*(old_u[i-1] - 2*old_u[i] + old_u[i+1]); //i  is known here
        printf("%f", new_u[i]); //i is not available for this
```

use braces like this

```
 for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
 {
    new_u[i] = old_u[i] + d/(h*h)*(old_u[i-1] - 2*old_u[i] + old_u[i+1]);
    printf("%f", new_u[i]);
 }
```

Comment: BTW, your indentation style suggests that you did not intend the printf to be a part of the `for i...` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The unknown identifier is `i`, not `new_u`; you need braces:

```
for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    new_u[i] = old_u[i] + d/(h*h)*(old_u[i-1] 
               - 2*old_u[i] + old_u[i+1]);
    if (i>1) putchar(' ');
    printf("%f", new_u[i]);
}
```

In your wrong version of the code `i` was visible only by the assignment to `new_u[i]` not by your `printf`

BTW, you probably want a space to be put between your numbers, like I did with `putchar`. Otherwise the output could be unreadable, e.g. `1.233.45` for two numbers `1.23` and `3.45`

Since you have a `for (int i=1;` loop the scope of `i` is only the (test, increment and) body of your `for`; in your case that body was a single assignment.

Comment: Yeah I know, why is that? I am obviously missing something simple but I have checked that i has values, why is it then an unknown identifier

Answer (score 0):

Just put a brace in the second for loop covering print function also...

```
for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
 {
    new_u[i] = old_u[i] + d/(h*h)*(old_u[i-1] - 2*old_u[i] + old_u[i+1]);
    printf("%f", new_u[i]);
 }
```

and answer to your above comment is that

1).  'i' is an unknown identifier because its out of scope now as it has got its scope for the second FOR loop only.

2).  'i' has values because you put the values in it in the FOR loop and after being out of scope also automatic variables doesn't gets destroyed, it stays there until it gets overwritten by some new variable while execution.